# Is it possible in AWS dynamo database to name object keys with dashed strings? or to apply command (update, delete) to dashed string keys?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, crud

My scenario is a dynamo database in aws, I've a table containing a structure like the following one:

```
{
  "data": {
    "23fc4fa8-0037-4d09-90be-506eed497a15": {
      "text": "first text"
    },
    "4708f80a-e301-48ab-8351-f598c4300600": {
      "text": "second text"
    }
  },
  "types": "type",
  "order": 3
}
```

My goal is to delete the second text, I receive from clientside the id `4708f80a-e301-48ab-8351-f598c4300600` so I'm building my call to delete that field only, in order to have this data after the removal operation:

```
{
  "data": {
    "23fc4fa8-0037-4d09-90be-506eed497a15": {
      "text": "first text"
    }
  },
  "types": "type",
  "order": 3
}
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
  const type = 'type'
  const id = '4708f80a-e301-48ab-8351-f598c4300600'
  const dynamoBd = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

  const params = {
    TableName: DB_TABLE,
    Key: {
      types: type
    },
    UpdateExpression : `REMOVE data.${id}`
  }

  await dynamoDbClient
    .update(params, (error, _) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`Error: `, error)
        return
      }
    })
    .promise()
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error:  ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "4708", near: ".4708f80a"
```

I believe the issue is the way this string is build `'REMOVE data.${id}'` that parsed look like this `'REMOVE data.4708f80a-e301-48ab-8351-f598c4300600`'

Any ideas how to solve this, thanks in advance to everyone who could help me out. Ps. if you find some documentation on aws website about it, could you also post it, because currently I couldn't find it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to build the `const params`, with the support of `ExpressionAttributeNames`:

The reason is that some keys or values might be keywords or contain special characters (like dash in the example). So `ExpressionAttributeNames` (for the example) and `ExpressionAttributeValues` are used to create substitute placeholders of the keys and values.

```
  const params = {
    TableName: DB_TABLE,
    Key: {
      types: type
    },
    UpdateExpression : `REMOVE #data.#id`,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#data': 'data',
      '#id': id
    }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't consider this as an edit of my question. This is the answer used to complete the question. So I don't see the issue.

Comment: You didn't provide any explanation, so I assumed you wanted to edit the question. Next time if you want to provide solution, please explain it properly.

Comment: Please explain your solution better. Remember, it's not just about _you_. It's about everyone who will read your question and answers in the future.